google colaboratoryにおけるcudaのバージョン変更
google colaboratoryでcuda11.4とcuDNN8.2を使いたいです。ですが、!nvcc --versionを実行すると、
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2020 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Mon_Nov_30_19:15:10_Pacific_Standard_Time_2020
Cuda compilation tools, release 11.2, V11.2.67
Build cuda_11.2.r11.2/compiler.29373293_0
と出て、バージョンが11.2となってしまいます。画像はシステム環境変数です。torch.cudaを使えるようにし、ver11.4にしたいです。よろしくお願いします。

この辺の記事が参考になるのでは？ ColabでCUDAとPyTorchとPythonをダウングレードする, 【備忘録】Google Colab上のCUDAバージョン変更 あとgoogle colaboratory上のソフトウェアの版数や設定などとWindowsの環境変数の間には何の関係も無いのでは？
